# How to implement zipWithIndex on HLists

Tags: scala, shapeless, hlist

Writting algorithm on `HList`, I need a `zipWithIndex` function. It is not at the shapeless library by now, so I decided to implement it.

It is quite obvious that it might be implemented as

```
hlist.zip(indexes)
```

where `indexes` is the `HList` of the indexes (0..n), that probably could be obtained this way:

```
val indexes = Nat._0 until hlist.length
```

Issue here is that `Nat` doesn't have `until` method. I haven't found any `Witness` for the `HList` index to use with `HList.map`.

What is the method I could use to obtain `HList` of `Nat`s starting with `Nat._0` till `hlist.length`?

Answer (score 6):

It might make sense to add something like this to Shapeless:

```
import shapeless._, ops.hlist.Prepend

trait Range[A <: Nat, B <: Nat] extends DepFn0 { type Out <: HList }

object Range {
  type Aux[A <: Nat, B <: Nat, Out0 <: HList] = Range[A, B] { type Out = Out0 }

  implicit def emptyRange[A <: Nat]: Aux[A, A, HNil] = new Range[A, A] {
    type Out = HNil
    def apply(): Out = HNil
  }

  implicit def slightlyBiggerRange[A <: Nat, B <: Nat, OutAB <: HList](implicit
    rangeAB: Aux[A, B, OutAB],
    appender: Prepend[OutAB, B :: HNil],
    witnessB: Witness.Aux[B]
  ): Aux[A, Succ[B], appender.Out] = new Range[A, Succ[B]] {
    type Out = appender.Out
    def apply(): Out = appender(rangeAB(), witnessB.value :: HNil)
  }
}

def range[A <: Nat, B <: Nat](implicit r: Range[A, B]): r.Out = r()
```

Now you can write `zipWithIndex` pretty cleanly:

```
import ops.hlist.{ Length, Zip }

def zipWithIndex[L <: HList, S <: Nat, R <: HList, Out <: HList](l: L)(implicit
  len: Length.Aux[L, S],
  range: Range.Aux[nat._0, S, R],
  zipper: Zip.Aux[L :: R :: HNil, Out]
): Out = l.zip(range())
```

And then:

```
import nat._

type Expected = (Int, _0) :: (Symbol, _1) :: (String, _2) :: HNil

val xs: Expected = zipWithIndex(1 :: 'a :: "foo" :: HNil)
```

You could also use a fold or a `ZippedWithIndex[L <: HList]` type class, both of which might be a little more concise, but less clearly composed out of independently useful pieces like `Range`.

Comment: Indeed it might :-) Also for `Coproducts` and tuples?

Comment: As a beginner to Shapeless, I don't fully understand it.  I also vote to include it in the Shapeless distribution.